# Check whether a string is the value of a dictionary item in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to check if a string matches any `d["vin"]` a list of disctionaries:

```
mylist = [{"vin":"A123"}, {"vin":"B234"}];
if "A123" in ???:
    # continue...
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
if any(d['vin'] == 'A123' for d in mylist):
```

This assumes that all `d` in `mylist` have that key; if that's not the case use `dict.get()`:

```
if any(d.get('vin') == 'A123' for d in mylist):
```

In either case, `any()` will short-circuit; it'll only test as many `d` as required to find a match. For your sample, only the first dictionary will be tested.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. Do you know something about the computation time of this?

Comment: @Freddi: worst case you'll loop through the whole list, testing all `d` in the list. If you need to do this often for a large list, create an inverse index.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
if any(d["vin"] == "A123" for d in mylist):
    # ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [{"vin":"A123"}, {"vin":"B234"}];

for lists in mylist:
   if "vin" in lists:
        # continue...do something
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `any` with `in`:

```
if any('A123' in d.values() for d in mylist):
```

Comment: This won't work: `dict.items()` iterates over `(key, value)` pairs. You might have meant `d.values()`, but even that won't check that **`d["vin"]`** alone contains the value.

Comment: But `d.values()` returns a list in Python 2. The OP specifically stated they are only interested in the `'vin'` key, not in *all* values. The value could be given to other keys as well, in which case it shouldn't be matched.